# log4j file is not getting created

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss, log4j

I have created log4j properties file within resource folder.Here is my log4j properties file code.

```
# LOG4J configuration
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, Appender1, Appender2

log4j.appender.Appender1 = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern = %-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.Appender2 = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File = C:/arnab/Logs/llllooooogggooo.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern = %-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

but the problem is in my destination folder log4j file is not getting created. I am using JBoss server.I tried a lot but did not get any result. Can anyone help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

The log4j.properties file should be placed in the proper classpath. 
If you are using maven project, then it should be under, src/main/resources/. Make sure you have the following dependencies, available in the application classpath,

- jboss-logmanager
- jboss-logging
- slf4j-log4j2

Comment: yes i have added the mentioned jar. But what changes need to be done in classpath? Can you give an example pls? or any link?

Comment: Can you let me know where have you placed the log4j,properties file in your app ? and which of the jars are the present ? All the 3 ? Is this a Maven project ?

Comment: I am using ANT build tool..i put my log4j file inside resources folder and whatever jar file u have mentioned all i have put in my project

Comment: okay, then how does your final packaged jar look like ? If the packaging is plain jar, the classpath starts from the root of the context. Hence, you need to place the file there.  Additionally, you can also have this property set and check if that works, -Dlog4j.configuration=file:"./your/properties/path/log4j.properties"